# Remove special character (ampersand) from a string with jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve something that 'should' be fairly straightforward, bit I can't find anything online to help me out.

I have some CSS class names that are being output with ampersands in them (its down to the system I'm using and is unavoidable). I'd like to use a little bit of jQuery to simply remove the ampersand, so a string that looks like:

class="Middle&East"

would be

class="MiddleEast"

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the context? Is this `class="Middle&East"` in HTML? Or JS? And why modify it with jQuery (since it would be done in the client side)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To replace them all you could;

```
$('[class*=\\&]').each(function()  {
    $(this)[0].className = $(this)[0].className.replace(/&/g,"");      
})
​
```

Comment: Can you please explain what "/&/g" is? I've never seen this kind of notation.

Comment: @sbunny It's a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
var class="Middle&East"
class.replace('&', '');
```

Comment: This would only replace the first occurrence. Use `/&/g` instead.

Comment: +1,You might want to update the answer to a global replace, just in case that is needed

Answer (score 1):

You will have to escape the `&` if you are using jquery

Try

`$(".Middle\\&East").removeClass("Middle&East").addClass("MiddleEast");`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jwkVD/)

General solution to remove `&` from classname

```
$(function(){
    $('[class*="&"]').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),cname = $this.attr('class').replace(/&/g,'');
        $this.attr('class',cname)

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along

```
$(".Middle&East").removeClass("Middle&East").addClass("MiddleEast");
```

Comment: Although that would work, I'm not always going to know what the class name is going to be, so it kind of need to be something a bit more dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to works for me :

```
$(function() {
    $('[class="Middle&East"]').toggleClass('Middle&East MiddleEast');
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U3r7G/

Answer (score 0):

```
var className = $(element).attr('class');
var modifiedClass = className.replace('&', '');
$(element).attr('class', modifiedClass);
```